Why can't I iteratively add ggplot objects to a list?
I've been stuck on this issue for a while. This is a simplified version of a larger code.
lc(df, months=c('May', 'June', 'August'))

This should give me the same plot 3 times. It gives me 3 different plots, 2 of them incorrect. I can't even wrap my head around what is happening. When I simply print(p) inside the loop, it works perfectly. Why doesn't this work? Thanks for any advice.
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ecotox)
df <- ecotox::lamprey_tox
lc<- function(data, dose='dose', months=c(), month='month', total='total', response='response'){

  data <- data%>% filter(month %in% c(months))

  myplots <- list()
  for (i in seq_along(months)){

    a <- data[data$month %in% months[i],]
    print(a)
    lc <- LC_probit((response/ total) ~ log10(as.numeric(dose)), p = c(50, 90),
                    weights = total,
                    data =a)
    LC50 <- lc$dose[1] #strip lc50
    LC90 <- lc$dose[2] #strip lc90
    p <- ggplot(data=a,aes(x=log10(as.numeric(dose)),y=(response/total)))+
             geom_point(size=4)+ 
             geom_smooth(method="glm", 
                         method.args=list(family=binomial(link="probit")), 
                         aes(weight=total),colour="blue",se=TRUE, level=0.95) +
             geom_segment(aes(x = log10(LC50), xend = log10(LC50), y=-Inf, yend=0.5), linetype='dashed', size=1) +
             geom_segment(aes(x = -Inf, xend = log10(LC50), y=0.5, yend=0.5), linetype='dashed', size=1) +
             geom_segment(aes(x = log10(LC90), xend = log10(LC90), y=-Inf, yend=0.9), linetype='dashed', size=1) +
             geom_segment(aes(x = -Inf, xend = log10(LC90), y=0.9, yend=0.9), linetype='dashed', size=1) 
 

myplots[[i]] <- p
  print(myplots[1]) 

    
    
  }
 
}




UPDATE:
Here is the source code for ecotox:LC_probit.
LC_probit <- function(formula, data, p = NULL,
                      weights = NULL,
                      subset = NULL, log_base = NULL,
                      log_x = TRUE,
                      het_sig = NULL,
                      conf_level = NULL,
                      conf_type = NULL,
                      long_output = TRUE) {
  
  model <- do.call("glm", list(formula = formula,
                               family = binomial(link = "probit"),
                               data = data,
                               weights = substitute(weights),
                               subset = substitute(subset)))
  
  # error message for missing weights argument in function call
  if(missing(weights)) {
    warning ("Are you using cbind(response, non-response) method as your y variable, if so do not weight the model. If you are using (response / total) method, model needs the total of test organisms per dose to weight the model properly",
             call. = FALSE)
  }

  if (is.null(p)) {
    p <- seq(1, 99, 1)
    warning("`p`argument has to be supplied otherwise LC values for 1-99 will be displayed", call. = FALSE)
  }
  
  
  
  chi_square <- sum(residuals.glm(model, type = "pearson") ^ 2)
  
  df <- df.residual(model)
  
  pgof <- pchisq(chi_square, df, lower.tail = FALSE)
  summary <- summary(model)
  b0 <- summary$coefficients[1]
  b1 <- summary$coefficients[2]
  intercept_se <- summary$coefficients[3]
  intercept_sig <- summary$coefficients[7]
  slope_se <- summary$coefficients[4]
  slope_sig <- summary$coefficients[8]
  z_value <- summary$coefficients[6]
  n <- df + 2
  est <- qnorm(p / 100)
  m <- (est - b0) / b1
  if (is.null(het_sig)) {
    het_sig <- 0.150
  }
  
  if (pgof < het_sig) {
    het <- chi_square / df
  } else {
    het <- 1
  }
  if (is.null(conf_type)) {
    conf_type <- c("fl")
  } else {
    
    conf_type <- c("dm")
    
  }
  
  if (conf_type == "fl") {
    if (pgof < het_sig) {
      vcova <- vcov(model) * het
    } else {
      vcova <- vcov(model)
    }
    var_b0 <- vcova[1, 1]
    var_b1 <- vcova[2, 2]
    cov_b0_b1 <- vcova[1, 2]
    if (is.null(conf_level)) {
      conf_level <- 0.95
    }
    
    t <- (1 - conf_level)
    
    t_2 <- (t / 2)
    
    if (pgof < het_sig) {
      tdis <- -qt(t_2, df = df)
    } else {
      tdis <- -qnorm(t_2)
    }
    g <- (tdis ^ 2 * var_b1) / (b1 ^ 2)
    cl_part_1 <- (g / (1 - g)) * (m + (cov_b0_b1 / var_b1))
    
    cl_part_2 <- (var_b0 + (2 *  cov_b0_b1 * m) + (m ^ 2 * var_b1) -
                    (g * (var_b0 - cov_b0_b1 ^ 2 / var_b1)))
    
    cl_part_3 <- (tdis / ((1 - g) * abs(b1))) * sqrt(cl_part_2)
    LCL <- (m + (cl_part_1 - cl_part_3))
    UCL <- (m + (cl_part_1 + cl_part_3))
    
  }
  cf <- -cbind(1, m) / b1
  se_1 <- ((cf %*% vcov(model)) * cf) %*% c(1, 1)
  se_2 <- as.numeric(sqrt(se_1))
  var_m <- (1 / (m ^ 2)) * (var_b0 + 2 * m * cov_b0_b1 +
                              m ^ 2 * var_b1)
  
  
  
  if (log_x == TRUE) {
    
    if(is.null(log_base)) {
      log_base <- 10
    }
    dose <- log_base ^ m
    LCL <- log_base ^ LCL
    UCL <- log_base ^ UCL
    se_2 <- log_base ^ se_2
  }
  
  if (log_x == FALSE) {
    dose <- m
    LCL <- LCL
    UCL <- UCL
    se_2 <- se_2
    
  }

  if (long_output == TRUE) {
    table <- tibble(p = p,
                    n = n,
                    dose = dose,
                    LCL = LCL,
                    UCL = UCL,
                    se = se_2,
                    chi_square = chi_square,
                    df = df,
                    pgof_sig = pgof,
                    h = het,
                    slope = b1,
                    slope_se = slope_se,
                    slope_sig = slope_sig,
                    intercept = b0,
                    intercept_se = intercept_se,
                    intercept_sig = intercept_sig,
                    z = z_value,
                    var_m = var_m,
                    covariance = cov_b0_b1)
  }
  
  if (long_output == FALSE) {
    table <- tibble(p = p,
                    n = n,
                    dose = dose,
                    LCL = LCL,
                    UCL = UCL)
  }
  return(table)
  
}

Here is the data for ecotox::lamprey_tox (the data I used in this example which is assigned to df.
structure(list(nominal_dose = c(0, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 
1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1.7, 
1.7, 1.7, 2, 2, 2, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 
3, 3, 3, 0, 2.7, 2.7, 3.3, 3.3, 3.7, 3.7, 4.1, 4.1, 4.5, 4.5, 
5, 5, 0, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2, 2.3, 2.3, 2.6, 2.6, 3, 3, 3.5, 3.5), 
    tank = c("S", "A", "L", "M", "B", "K", "N", "C", "I", "O", 
    "D", "J", "P", "E", "H", "Q", "F", "G", "R", "A", "B", "M", 
    "N", "C", "L", "O", "D", "K", "P", "E", "J", "Q", "F", "I", 
    "R", "G", "H", "S", "M", "A", "L", "B", "K", "C", "J", "D", 
    "I", "E", "H", "F", "G", "m", "A", "L", "B", "K", "C", "J", 
    "D", "I", "E", "H", "F", "G"), month = c("May", "May", "May", 
    "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", 
    "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "June", 
    "June", "June", "June", "June", "June", "June", "June", "June", 
    "June", "June", "June", "June", "June", "June", "June", "June", 
    "June", "June", "August", "August", "August", "August", "August", 
    "August", "August", "August", "August", "August", "August", 
    "August", "August", "September", "September", "September", 
    "September", "September", "September", "September", "September", 
    "September", "September", "September", "September", "September"
    ), dose = c(0.19, 0.79, 0.8, 0.76, 1.36, 1.22, 1.18, 1.54, 
    1.44, 1.36, 1.69, 1.66, 1.6, 1.92, 1.86, 1.8, 2.2, 2.18, 
    2.1, 0.06, 1.67, 1.69, 1.67, 2.09, 2.1, 2.09, 2.37, 2.38, 
    2.39, 2.55, 2.59, 2.59, 2.68, 2.78, 2.8, 3.07, 3.09, 3.11, 
    0.04, 2.81, 2.78, 3.42, 3.42, 3.87, 3.84, 4.25, 4.26, 4.68, 
    4.69, 5.19, 5.22, 0.05, 1.45, 1.48, 1.99, 2.01, 2.29, 2.32, 
    2.62, 2.65, 3.09, 3.06, 3.59, 3.6), response = c(0, 0, 1, 
    0, 13, 10, 7, 16, 11, 17, 17, 19, 18, 22, 19, 18, 20, 20, 
    20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 6, 4, 4, 11, 8, 10, 
    11, 9, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 6, 9, 4, 10, 5, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 
    4, 3, 9, 6, 10, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10), survive = c(20, 20, 19, 
    20, 8, 9, 11, 4, 10, 3, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 10, 9, 
    10, 9, 11, 10, 10, 9, 10, 10, 10, 4, 5, 6, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 
    10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 4, 1, 6, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 6, 7, 
    1, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0), total = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 19, 
    18, 20, 21, 20, 20, 20, 20, 22, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 9, 
    10, 9, 11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 10, 11, 11, 10, 
    11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -64L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(nominal_dose = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), tank = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), month = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), dose = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), response = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), survive = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), total = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))


Here is an expanded version of what I want to do. But eventually, I'll build it out more to be more flexible. But this shows the problem clearly. I am using Rstudio. I have seeing this in the viewing pane.
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ecotox)
df <- ecotox::lamprey_tox
lc<- function(data, dose='dose', months=c(), month='month', total='total', response='response'){
  
  data <- data%>% filter(month %in% c(months))
  
  myplots <- list()
  for (i in seq_along(months)){
    
    a <- data[data$month %in% months[i],]
    print(a)
    lc <- LC_probit((response/ total) ~ log10(as.numeric(dose)), p = c(50, 90),
                    weights = total,
                    data =a)
    LC50 <- lc$dose[1] #strip lc50
    LC90 <- lc$dose[2] #strip lc90
    p <- ggplot(data=a,aes(x=log10(as.numeric(dose)),y=(response/total)))+
      geom_point(size=4)+ 
      geom_smooth(method="glm", 
                  method.args=list(family=binomial(link="probit")), 
                  aes(weight=total),colour="blue",se=TRUE, level=0.95) +
      geom_segment(aes(x = log10(LC50), xend = log10(LC50), y=-Inf, yend=0.5), linetype='dashed', size=1) +
      geom_segment(aes(x = -Inf, xend = log10(LC50), y=0.5, yend=0.5), linetype='dashed', size=1) +
      geom_segment(aes(x = log10(LC90), xend = log10(LC90), y=-Inf, yend=0.9), linetype='dashed', size=1) +
      geom_segment(aes(x = -Inf, xend = log10(LC90), y=0.9, yend=0.9), linetype='dashed', size=1) 
    
    
    myplots[[i]] <- p

    
    
    
  }
  
  return(list(myplots[[1]], myplots[[2]], myplots[[3]]))

  
}



This is what I get, which is not what I want



If I print p in the loop, I get the expected results, but it takes away all flexibility of my function.
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ecotox)
df <- ecotox::lamprey_tox
lc<- function(data, dose='dose', months=c(), month='month', total='total', response='response'){
  
  data <- data%>% filter(month %in% c(months))
  
  myplots <- list()
  for (i in seq_along(months)){
    
    a <- data[data$month %in% months[i],]
    print(a)
    lc <- LC_probit((response/ total) ~ log10(as.numeric(dose)), p = c(50, 90),
                    weights = total,
                    data =a)
    LC50 <- lc$dose[1] #strip lc50
    LC90 <- lc$dose[2] #strip lc90
    p <- ggplot(data=a,aes(x=log10(as.numeric(dose)),y=(response/total)))+
      geom_point(size=4)+ 
      geom_smooth(method="glm", 
                  method.args=list(family=binomial(link="probit")), 
                  aes(weight=total),colour="blue",se=TRUE, level=0.95) +
      geom_segment(aes(x = log10(LC50), xend = log10(LC50), y=-Inf, yend=0.5), linetype='dashed', size=1) +
      geom_segment(aes(x = -Inf, xend = log10(LC50), y=0.5, yend=0.5), linetype='dashed', size=1) +
      geom_segment(aes(x = log10(LC90), xend = log10(LC90), y=-Inf, yend=0.9), linetype='dashed', size=1) +
      geom_segment(aes(x = -Inf, xend = log10(LC90), y=0.9, yend=0.9), linetype='dashed', size=1) 
    
    
 
print(p)
  }
  


  
}

You can see that now the geom_smooth and the geom_segmentlayers line up as intended.




Probably a lazy evaluation problem. Convert your for loop to lapply.

Your function lc doesn't return anything. Did you want it to return the myplots list?

I presume you need to add myplots between your last two }, so that the function outputs that list object once it has been populated.

@MrFlick, in the larger set of code it does, but I’m trying to sort out issues with building a list of ggplot objects. I’m using print to trouble shoot, and show the root of the problem (or at least where the problem is).

As @datawookie points out in their answer, you should expect three different plots from your current implementation.  If this is not what you intend, then we need to know what your desired output actually is.  If it is the "same plot three times", then we need to know which, if any of the three current plots you want?  or is it a different plot?  (And, perhaps, why you want three copies of the same plot...)

@Limey, I eventually want 3 different plots. But since I assigned May to index 1 of myplots I expect that each pass through the loop should print the first index (which should still be the plot for May) 3 times. This is only diagnostic. I’m trying to build a list (and eventually a grid) of length i plots. But for some reason myplots[[1]] gets over written even when i is not equal to 1. Why would myplots[[1]] print differently 3 times when you only assigned it to a one ggplot object?

Do you see three identical plots (corresponding to May) and then three different plots, one for each month?  If so, that could be expected behaviour, since you don't assign the value retuned by lc to an object.  The three identical plots are your diagnostic.  The three different plots are the return value, printed by default on return from the function.  If that's not what you mean then we really need more information to clarify the situation.

@Limey, that’s exactly what I expect. But that’s not what I get. I never get 3 identical plots. I get 3 (incorrect) plots. The geom_segment and geom_smooth layers don’t match up. It’s so bizarre and I can’t comprehend why it’s happening because I’ve done this so many times in the past without any hiccups. I think someone suggested a lazy loading problem, but I’m not sure how to fix that.  I’ll try adding a return to the function, but I think I tried that originally.

I was the one who suggested it was a lazy evaluation problem, but with no test data (I don't have the ecotox package) and no sight of the unexpected output, I'm simply guessing...  And where do you "see" what you see?  In the RStudio viewer pane?  In a markdown document? Somewhere else?  As I wrote earlier, without more information, we are simply guessing...

@Limey, I added more information.

The fact that the problem "goes away" when you add "debug prints" strongly suggests this is a lazy evaluation problem, as I first suspected.  I can't supply a definitive fix as your code is still not reproducible - I don't have the LC_probit_2 and it seems not to be part of the ecotox package.  (Please consider using reprex to confirm that your code is indeed reproducible.)  But, if I am correct, the solution is simple: convert your code to use lapply given the template I gave you in my answer.  Have you tried that? How did it go?  I will add an untested suggestion to my answer.

@Limey, sorry. I fixed it, just use LC_probit.

This is not a complete answer to your question.  It is intended to show you how to convert your for loop to an lapply call.  This will remove lazy evaluation as the root cause of your problem as the *apply family of functions use forced evaluation, whereas for loops use lazy evaluation.
As you're using the tidyverse (and since, as I mentioned earlier, I don't have ecotox), I'm using the starwars data frame.  Conversion to your use case should be straightforward.
lapply takes (at least) two arguments.  The first is a vector, the second a function.  lapply applies the function to each of the values in the vector in turn, passing the value from the vector to the function as its first argument.  lapply returns the results of the function calls in a list.
I select a few species from those represented in the data and plot height against mass my species.
library(tidyverse)

lc <- function(d, speciesList) {
  lapply(
    speciesList,
    function(x) {
      d %>% 
        filter(species == x) %>% 
        ggplot() +
          geom_point(aes(x = height, y = mass, colour = homeworld)) +
          labs(title = paste0("Species: ", x))
    }
  )
}

starwars %>% lc(c("Human", "Droid"))

This gives
[[1]]

[[2]]

Warning messages:
1: Removed 15 rows containing missing values or values outside the scale range (`geom_point()`). 
2: Removed 2 rows containing missing values or values outside the scale range (`geom_point()`). 

in the console and two graphs in the Plots pane:


Of course, facet_wrap(), facet_grid() or group_walk() would be more natural ways of doing this, but my purpose here is not to be natural but to explain how to use lapply.
Edit
Following OP's edit to the question, here is some untested (as I don't have the ecotox package and it is not obvious where the LC_probit_2 function comes from) code that converts OP's function to use lapply. I am not convinced that the month, total and response parameters to the lc function are necessary.
lc <- function(data, dose='dose', months=c(), month='month', total='total', response='response'){
  lapply(
    seq_along(months),
    function(i) {
      a <- data[data$month %in% months[i],]
      lc <- LC_probit_2((response/ total) ~ log10(as.numeric(dose)), p = c(50, 90),
                        weights = total,
                        data = a)
      LC50 <- lc$dose[1] #strip lc50
      LC90 <- lc$dose[2] #strip lc90
      ggplot(data = a, aes(x = log10(as.numeric(dose)), y = (response/total))) +
        geom_point(size = 4) + 
        geom_smooth(
          method="glm", 
          method.args=list(family = binomial(link = "probit")), 
          aes(weight = total), colour = "blue", se = TRUE, level = 0.95
        ) +
        geom_segment(aes(x = log10(LC50), xend = log10(LC50), y=-Inf, yend=0.5), linetype='dashed', size=1) +
        geom_segment(aes(x = -Inf, xend = log10(LC50), y=0.5, yend=0.5), linetype='dashed', size=1) +
        geom_segment(aes(x = log10(LC90), xend = log10(LC90), y=-Inf, yend=0.9), linetype='dashed', size=1) +
        geom_segment(aes(x = -Inf, xend = log10(LC90), y=0.9, yend=0.9), linetype='dashed', size=1) 
    }
  )
}

If you want to adopt a more tidyverse-pure approach, the following may also be an option:
lc <- function(data, dose='dose', months=c()){
  data %>% 
    filter(month %in% months) %>% 
    group_by(month) %>% 
    group_map(
      function(.x, .y) {
        lc <- LC_probit_2((response/ total) ~ log10(as.numeric(dose)), p = c(50, 90),
                          weights = total,
                          data = .x)
        LC50 <- lc$dose[1] #strip lc50
        LC90 <- lc$dose[2] #strip lc90
        .x %>% ggplot(aes(x = log10(as.numeric(dose)), y = (response/total))) +
          geom_point(size = 4) + 
          geom_smooth(
            method="glm", 
            method.args=list(family = binomial(link = "probit")), 
            aes(weight = total), colour = "blue", se = TRUE, level = 0.95
          ) +
          geom_segment(aes(x = log10(LC50), xend = log10(LC50), y=-Inf, yend=0.5), linetype='dashed', size=1) +
          geom_segment(aes(x = -Inf, xend = log10(LC50), y=0.5, yend=0.5), linetype='dashed', size=1) +
          geom_segment(aes(x = log10(LC90), xend = log10(LC90), y=-Inf, yend=0.9), linetype='dashed', size=1) +
          geom_segment(aes(x = -Inf, xend = log10(LC90), y=0.9, yend=0.9), linetype='dashed', size=1) 
      }
    )
}


If I use the lapply approach, can I save the plot as an object, to be bounded together in a grid? I tried using this approach and when I saved the plot to p[[i]], I couldn't access anything that (should have been) saved. I just get a blank list that I created before the lapply.

Just assign the return value of lc to an object.  That will be your list.  There are many, many examples of how to use lists both here on SO and elsewhere on the web.

If you want to create a grid of plots, perhaps facet_wrap or facet_grid would be simpler solutions.  (They would remove the need for an intermediate list, for a start...)  This is beginning to sound like an XY problem

The reason that you are getting three different plots is that you are filtering out a different subset of the data in each iteration.
I've inserted another print() into the loop.
lc <- function(data, dose='dose', months=c(), month='month', total='total', response='response') {
  data <- data%>% filter(month %in% c(months))
  
  myplots <- list()
  
  for (i in seq_along(months)){
    print(paste("Plotting data for", months[i]))
    a <- data[data$month %in% months[i],]
    
    lc <- LC_probit(
      (response/ total) ~ log10(as.numeric(dose)), p = c(50, 90),
      weights = total,
      data =a
    )
    LC50 <- lc$dose[1]
    LC90 <- lc$dose[2]
    
    myplots[[i]] <- ggplot(
      data=a,
      aes(x=log10(as.numeric(dose)),y=(response/total))
    )+
      geom_point(size=4)+ 
      geom_smooth(
        method="glm", 
        method.args=list(family=binomial(link="probit")), 
        aes(weight=total),colour="blue",se=TRUE, level=0.95
      ) +
      geom_segment(aes(x = log10(LC50), xend = log10(LC50), y=-Inf, yend=0.5), linetype='dashed', size=1) +
      geom_segment(aes(x = -Inf, xend = log10(LC50), y=0.5, yend=0.5), linetype='dashed', size=1) +
      geom_segment(aes(x = log10(LC90), xend = log10(LC90), y=-Inf, yend=0.9), linetype='dashed', size=1) +
      geom_segment(aes(x = -Inf, xend = log10(LC90), y=0.9, yend=0.9), linetype='dashed', size=1) 
  }
  
  myplots
}

The output from lc(df, months=c('May', 'June', 'August')) looks like this:
[1] "Plotting data for May"
[1] "Plotting data for June"
[1] "Plotting data for August"

The reason is this:
a <- data[data$month %in% months[i],]

On the first iteration this extracts the data for the month of May, then June on the next iteration and finally July. Since the data for these months differ, so do the plots.
To validate this, change the filtering line to this:
a <- data[data$month %in% months[1],]

Now you get three plots, all of which are based on the data for May.
It would be helpful to understand what you are trying to achieve. The current implementation makes sense to me and I would expect three distinct plots since you are using three different subsets of the data.

Is the filtering line you proposed not the same as the one I have? And I just posted more explanation in the comments, but I can expand if needed.

Sorry, you are right: a typo. I have corrected my second filter command to use 1 as index rather than i.

I added more information, let me know if it is enough.
